# Wcf Data Service 5.2 IgnoreProperty fail

Tags: wcf-data-services

I am exposing EF5 CF data with WCF Data Services 5.2, on one of my entity I have an `enum`, I read about this and set the `IgnoreProperties('')` attribute on my class.

But I still have an exception :

> "The property '' on the type '' is an 'EnumType'. It is not an handled primitive type" (sorry for the translation the exception is in french on my workstation)

I went through this post :  [Ignore properties attribute not working in WCF Data Services 5.0 RTM Release](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/ffeee9e2-b96c-4b16-8ab6-d48de066f5b7) and removed all reference to System.Data.Services 4.0.0.0 on all the solution.
To be sure I even did a text search in all the solution files using the explorer

The debug Module windows shows that I don't have System.Data.Services loaded.

The weird thing is that using fusion log I see that `System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` is loaded somewhere in my app and I really can not figure out where.

I tried to temporarily remove  all `system.data.services.*` from the GAC and it still fails with the same exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read on the MSDN forum thread below, it says that IgnoreProperties attribute is only supported for ReflectionProvider and not for EF provider.

Comment: thank Pratik, you are right, I should have read msdn more carefully

Comment: If you dont need the enum in the database adding the [NotMapped] data  annotation attribute fixed it for me